# Add Data attributes in typoscript to a link

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

i have a question regarding typoscript. I am new to typo3 and i am just looking into things.

I know i can do something like this in typoscript:

```
stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
ATagTitle.field = title
```

is it possible to put in a data-attribute to the a tag as well? Something like this:

```
ATagData.field = data-toggle="hover"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a TEXT object, then you should take a look at »typolink« and »ATagParams« (eg: »typolink.ATagParams = class="foo"«)

Since you posted »ATagTitle« I know that you work with a navigation object. In there you may use »ATagParams« as well:

```
ATagParams = data-toggle="hover"
```

See reference for TypoScript TMENU items: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html?highlight=atagparams